# Get the index of the first uppercase letter of a string in R?

Tags: r, string, indexing, uppercase

I'm trying to get the index of the first character of a string in R.  But most of the answer's I've searched check if the whole string is uppercase with `grepl`.  Python can do this easily, but I haven't found a a library that can do this in R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're starting with something like:

```
x <- c("stRing", "strIng", "String", "sTRIng", "string")
```

You can try:

```
sapply(gregexpr("[A-Z]", x), `[`, 1)
## [1]  3  4  1  2 -1
```

---

There's also the "stringi" package, with which you can use:

```
library(stringi)
stri_locate_first_regex(x, "[A-Z]")
##      start end
## [1,]     3   3
## [2,]     4   4
## [3,]     1   1
## [4,]     2   2
## [5,]    NA  NA
```

---

As pointed out by @lmo in the comments, `regexpr` also works and removes the need for `sapply`:

```
regexpr("[A-Z]", x)
## [1]  3  4  1  2 -1
## attr(,"match.length")
## [1]  1  1  1  1 -1
## attr(,"useBytes")
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward way would be splitting each string into singe letter vector and test which is in uppercase letters:

```
x <- c("stRing", "strIng", "String", "string", "sTRIng") # from the other answer

sapply(strsplit(x, ''), function(y) which(y %in% LETTERS)[1])

# [1]  3  4  1 NA  2
```